# Reset to defaults of autocomplete and drop down form fields with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have 2 forms on a page. One has id `dropdownmenu`. When one of the values is selected (on change) the value gets posted to `action.php`. The other form with id `search_form` is an autocomplete form, value is also posted to `action.php`.

I would like to empty the form with id `search_form` when the user chooses a value with the dropdownmenu form and posts that value. And I would like to put the value of the dropdownmenu form back to `one` (default) when a user posts a value with the autocomplete form.

The dropdownmenu form with be used to select a province and make a search based on that. The autocomplete form will be used to select a city and make a search based on that. It is not right if they both have a value. At least not visible for the user.

My knowledge of javascript is limited. I searched everywhere and tried lots of combinations with `$('#search_form').reset()`, `this.reset()`, `clearForm()`, `resetForm()` but nothing seems to work. Below is my complete code.

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
      $(function () {
        $('form').on('change', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({   
         type: 'post',                                   
         url: 'action.php',                          
         data: $('form').serialize(),                       
         dataType: 'html',                 
         success: function(response){                  
            $("#responsecontainer").html(response);   
         }
        });
        });
      });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
      $("#search_box").autocomplete({
      source: "/includes/search.php",
      minLength: 2,
         select: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.item){
            $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
            }
            $.ajax({   
            type: 'post',                                    
            url: 'action.php',                            
            data: $('form').serialize(),                      
            dataType: 'html',                 
            success: function(response){  
               $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
            }
            });
         }
      });
   });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="dropdownmenu" action="/" method="post"> 
<select class="form-control" name="provincie" id="provincie">  
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
    <option value="five">Five</option>
</select>
</form>  

<form id="search_form" action="/" method="post">
<input id="search_box" type="text" name="search_box" /></form>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>  

<div id="responsecontainer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To reset `#search_box` `autocomplete` field:

```
$("#search_box").val('')
```

To reset `#provincie` `select (dropdown)` :

```
$('#provincie').find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
//or
$('#provincie').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
```